# How to invert icons when selected in NSOutlineView or NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview, nsoutlineview

In my App I use icons within a `NSOutlineView` and `NSTableView` (through `NSImageCell`).

The icons look fine, but when the row is selected the icons aren't visible very well:

[image: current]

In Finder, for example the selected icon gets a white negative:

[image]

How can I achieve this effect in my App?

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted your image to be automatically tinted by Cocoa, you need to make sure `isTemplate` is set to `YES`. Read more about this at https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSImage/setTemplate:

However, since you prefer your images to be in full color in their normal state, then using template images isn't an option for you since it would tint it grey, or as needed by the context. Now you have to choose one of two options:

1. Provide an alternate image which is a white version of the normal one and switch in/out depending on the selected state of the
   cell
2. Generate an alternate image by tinting your normal one yourself and switch it as stated above

Comment: I declared **Render As** is set to `Template Image` (using `.xcassets` that is) but the result still looks the same. I also tried `setTemplate` on the `NSImage` directly with the same result.

Comment: Use black colour icons with isTemplate